# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with Android <aaptexec> task

Tags: java, android, ant, android-build

I am trying to build an Android project but I am getting the following exception from the Android target:

```
resource-src:
     [echo] Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...

BUILD FAILED
V:\myAndroid\build_Android.xml:80: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.parseDependencyFile(DependencyGraph.java:180)
        at com.android.ant.DependencyGraph.<init>(DependencyGraph.java:54)
        at com.android.ant.SingleDependencyTask.initDependencies(SingleDependencyTask.java:87)
        at com.android.ant.AaptExecTask.execute(AaptExecTask.java:477)
```

My aaptexec executable is as follows but I am not able to understand why is failing on `libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path`:

```
<aaptexec
    executable="${aapt}"
    command="package"
    verbose="false"
    manifest="${stage.dir}/OMCP/AndroidManifest.xml"
    androidjar="${android.jar}"
    rfolder="${gen.absolute.dir}"
    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
    libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
>
    <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
</aaptexec>
```

Can anyone help me on this?